# VBA to clean characters from CELL

Tags: excel, vba, replace

VBA to clean characters from CELL,  This script is meant to through all worksheets in an open work book and remove special characters (so I can rename the **TAB with the CELL**) However it is only cleaning the page from which the script is run.

```
Sub CleanChar()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myString As String
Dim newString As String

For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        myString = Range("A1").Value
        newString = Replace(Replace(myString, ":", ""), """", "")
        Range("A1").Offset().Value = newString
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: try referring to ws to fully qualify the range, so ws.Range("A1").Value instead of just Range("A1").Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that you are lacking a `.` in front of your `Range` objects.  You state `With ws` but then don't actually use `ws`, so your `Range` object is only referring to one worksheet.

Try this slightly modified code:

```
Sub CleanChar()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myString As String
    Dim newString As String

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            myString = .Range("A1").Value
            newString = Replace(Replace(myString, ":", ""), """", "")
            .Range("A1").Offset().Value = newString
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```